# Is there a way to bypass dependencies in an Azure multistage pipeline?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

```
 - stage: DeployToIVT
    displayName: Deploy ${{join(' AND ', parameters.ivtEnv )}}
    dependsOn:
    - Build
    condition: |
        and
        (
          eq(dependencies.Build.result, 'Succeeded'),
          
            
            or
            (
              
              startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'),
              startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/refresh/')
            )   
        )
```

I have a master.yml that we use for multistage pipelines.
The stage that deploys to QA is conditional based with a dependency on a successful build.
Is there a way to uncheck build and just have the deploy stage checked in order to bypass that build dependency?
When I try that it skips that stage all together and does nothing. I have tried adding a condition to say

```
  in(dependencies.Build.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
```

But the above does not work either.

Thanks

Comment: Could you use `condition: always()`? Though in that scenario it would run even if everything before it failed, which you may not want.

Comment: Thats @joelforsyth I was able to use '' for an empty value in the condition and it lets me uncheck build and run a stage just to deploy ie.
in(dependencies.Build.result, 'Succeeded','SucceededWithIssues','Skipped',''),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team does something similar. We skip over the build stage and reuse artifacts from previous builds or bypass entire environments if we need to do a hotfix, etc.

We use a technique similar to following, where we add a variable at queue time that can shortcut conditions:

```
 - stage: Build
   displayName: 'CI'
   condition: ne(variables['deployWithoutBuild'], 'true')
   ...
 
 - stage: DeployToIVT
   displayName: Deploy ${{join(' AND ', parameters.ivtEnv )}}
   dependsOn:
    - Build
   condition: |
      or(
        and(
          in(dependencies.Build.result, 'Succeeded','SucceededWithIssues','Skipped',''),         
          or(
              startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'),
              startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/refresh/')
            )   
        ),
        eq(variables['deployWithoutBuild'], 'true')
      )
```

I believe checking for a `''` build result was to accommodate if the stage was not included in the list of stages to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot bryanbcook. that worked! in my case using ' ' after skipped is working w/o a variable.  I tried adding another condition like the one above but i get the error that condition is already being used.  I then tried an expression as ${{ if ne(variables['deployWithoutBuild'], 'true') }}: then set a parameter at the top w/ a default of false.  I can still skip the build though when running the pipeline if they didnt supply deployWithoutBuild: true on the azure-pipeline.yml file.  I am sure i have something out of place but not sure what.

Comment: The conditions can be a pain to test. If this helped, would you mind accepting or upvoting the answer?